# Number of strings of length n using k characters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Find number of ways to form a string of length n using k characters such that at most two adjacent characters can be same.

I tried to solve this problem in two parts:
 1. Find number of strings of length n using k characters so that no adjacent character are same .
 2. Find number of string of length n using k characters so that there exists at least one pair of exactly two adjacent same characters (and there cannot be more than two adjacent characters same) .

For the first part I approached it as:

```
no. of ways to put a character on string position 1 = k
no. of ways to put a character on string position 2 = k-1 (as it must be different from last used character)
.
.
no. of ways to put a character on string position n = k-1
: 
So no. of strings = k(k-1)(k-1).... n-1 times = k(k-1)^(n-1)
```

Now for the second part there could be any(1 to n/2) number of pairs of same adjacent characters but I don't understand how to approach this.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you describe what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Add what you've tried and people (and me) will help you to get the desired answer!

Comment: Added my initial thoughts in the question now.

Comment: @HrishikeshGoyal I'll try to help you! The question does not say anything about the k characters? Are they all different?

Comment: yes.. they are different.

Comment: @HrishikeshGoyal If they are all different isn't then impossible to have a sequence of length n with two adjacent characters the same?

Comment: They are different... but they can be used repeatedly as fas as no more than two adjacent characters are same. e.g if k={a,b,c} and n=5 then aabbc, abbcc, caabb.., etc. are valid strings

Answer (score 1):

This question is kinda weird since you didn't say anything about repetition. Supposing our sequence of length n allows repetition, here is how I would approach it:

---

We want to create sequences of length n from a set of $k$ characters allowing repetition with the constraint that at most two adjacent characters can be the same.

Let's use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

First, the number of sequences of length $n$ from $k$ elements allowing repetition is: $k^n$.

Now let's define the following sets for $ 3 \leq p \leq n$:
$$
S_p=\{\text{Sequences of length n with p adjacent characters the same}\}
$$
Therefore our final answer is: $k^n- |\bigcup_{p=3}^n S_p|$. Let's then calculate the cardinality of that union.

Clearly those sets are all disjoint, therefore:
$$
|\bigcup_{p=3}^n S_p| = |S_3| + |S_4| + \cdots + |S_n|
$$
And we can use the following strategy to calculate the cardinality of $|S_p|$: From our $k$ characters, select $1$ and place it in $p$ adjacent positions. There are $n-p+1$ possibilities to choose adjacent positions. Now we need to let the remaining $n-p$ positions to select, without repetition, characters from the $k-1$ remaining, and that can be done in $(k-1)(k-2)\cdots (k-n+p)=\frac{(k-1)!}{(k-n+p-1)!}$ ways. Therefore, by multiplication principle we get:
$$
|S_p|=k\cdot (n-p+1) \cdot \frac{(k-1)!}{(k-n+p-1)!} = \frac{k!(n-p+1)}{(k-n+p-1)!}
$$
which follows that:
$$
|\bigcup_{p=3}^n S_p| = \sum_{p=3}^{n} \frac{k!(n-p+1)}{(k-n+p-1)!}
$$
Finally, our answer is:
$$
k^n - \sum_{p=3}^{n} \frac{k!(n-p+1)}{(k-n+p-1)!}
$$

---

**Sanity Check:** Suppose $n=4$ and $K=\{a,b\}$. Therefore all sequences are:
\begin{align*}
(a,a,a,a)&\\
(a,a,b,b)&,(a,b,a,b)\\
(a,a,a,b)&,(a,a,b,a),(a,b,a,a),(b,a,a,a)\\
(b,b,b,b)&\\
(b,b,a,a)&,(b,a,b,a)\\
(b,b,b,a)&,(b,b,a,b),(b,a,b,b),(a,b,b,b)\\
(b,a,a,b)&,(a,b,b,a)
\end{align*}
There are $2^4=16$ sequences. Removing the ones that we don't want to count, that is, sequences with three or more adjacent repetitions, we have the remaining sequences:
$$
(a,a,b,b),(a,b,a,b)\\
(a,a,b,a),(a,b,a,a)\\
(b,b,a,a),(b,a,b,a)\\
(b,b,a,b),(b,a,b,b)\\
(b,a,a,b),(a,b,b,a)
$$
There are $10$ sequences. Now let's check if our answer is going to validate to the same number:
\begin{align*}
k^n - \sum_{p=3}^{n} \frac{k!(n-p+1)}{(k-n+p-1)!} &= 2^4 - \frac{2!(4-3+1)}{(2-4+3-1)!} - \frac{2!(4-4+1)}{(2-4+4-1)!}\\
&= 16 - \frac{2!(2)}{(0)!} - \frac{2!(1)}{(1)!}\\
&= 16 - 4 - 2 = 10
\end{align*}
So it seems to make sense. I'm not sure if it's 100% correct, but that's what I've done to try to solve it. Hope it helps!

Comment: From our k characters, select 1 and place it in p adjacent positions. There are n−p+1 possibilities to choose adjacent positions. 

Here there can be more than n-p+1 ways to choose p adjacent positions. For example say n =7 and k=3  
      
x: chosen position , - : available positions
   
xxx----    ,  
-xxx---   ,   
--xxx--  , 
---xxx- , 
----xxx , 
xxx-xxx ,

Comment: Also for remaining n−p positions to select, repetition is allowed. Just that there can't be more than p adjacent characters. For example if k = {a,b,c} and n = 6, p = 3 =>   aaabcb, aaabac, aaabab are not considered in (k−1)(k−2)⋯(k−n+p) computation.